# CORS file upload for angularjs with IE8 support

Tags: angularjs, cors, multipartform-data, jquery-file-upload, form-data

I am seeking an easy and light weight way to upload a small file to a REST API using CORS.
I am using the following plugin:
[angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

The problem is that it uses swf fallback for deprecated browsers, that don't support the formData object(such as IE 8 and IE 9).

I have opened an issue on github on this matter, but no luck so far.

Which means that I cannot upload a file using CORS on those browsers, which is something I cannot allow (many users still use IE).

Comment: Cross-origin file uploading is not a trivial task.  If you are looking for a complete solution for all browsers, including IE7, and you don't want to rely on jQuery, flash, or any other dependency, consider using [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  Full disclosure: I maintain this library.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for an open source solution

Comment: That is an open source solution.  The code is all visible at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that, can you please take a look on my recent question about bluimp?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any working knowledge of that library's code.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

angular-file-upload has a solution for old broswers(such as ie8,9),

just put those code before "angular-file-upload-shim.js"

```
<script>
//optional need to be loaded before angular-file-upload-shim(.min).js
FileAPI = {
    jsPath: '/js/FileAPI.min.js/folder/',
    staticPath: '/flash/FileAPI.flash.swf/folder/'
}
</script>
```

you can visit [this page on github for more detail](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload).

Comment: I just want to emphasis the fact that this is only the path to the file, without the file's name.